# The name of the term for forming noun

Tags: terminology

What do you say
if you change the shape of noun
from singlar form to plural form
or vice versa ?

The property of the noun
such as singular form
and plural form are called ( plurality ? ),
and the change of the noun form
is called (    ).

Comment: *Pluralising* and *singularising*?

Comment: This question might be better on [linguistics.se]  The property that some nouns have is called *number*  (English nouns have two numbers, singular and plural but other languages have more complex number systems). In languages with complex number systems, the number is part of the noun's declension, but in English you *pluralise* singular nouns.

Comment: also "inflect":  see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293154/

Comment: Thank you (^^)

According to the number of the subject,
you have to inflect the noun.

If the number of the subject is more than one,
you have to inflect the number of the noun, which means
you have to plurarise it.